# Price of self-transfer tickets versus separate tickets

Tags: tickets, airport-transfer, self-transfer

Currently, I am looking for flights from Siem Reap (Cambodia, REP) to Jakarta. There are not direct flights, so I'll need a transfer. Most options are listed as self-transfer (on skyscanner) which basically makes them just two separate tickets without any guarantee of making the connection.

Now, I can also book two separate tickets, a few days apart and spend some time in the city where I am transferring (visa I would need anyhow).

My question is: is there generally a price difference between booking two tickets at once via, for example, Skyscanner and booking them separately (with different airlines or dates)?

Answer (score 1):

1: Some airline offers Siem Reap to Jakarta one-stop journey with one PNR. one PNR means one ticket that mean luggage will be auto transfer to next flight but its high expensive(Thai Air offer like this flight will cost 443$).

2: but if you book two separate tickets with two PNR you can find very cheap ticket near 170$. always remember no guarantee for this method. if your first flight delay and second flight missed then you have to take the second ticket again. always book a ticket with up to 5 hours time gaps.on this method, you have to pass immigration also then check visa also transfer country.

3: if you book both tickets one time sometimes this method price also a little high. time gaps also you cant change.

both 2 and 3 points are the same no guarantee and the second method you can customise your time gaps.

Have a nice journey

Comment: I am aware of how it works, but I wonder mainly about the prics, which you address in point 3.  So you're saying that it is more expensive to book both tickets at once? Can you elaborate on that (because I expected it to be the other way around)